# CSS way to achieve solid continuous line edges between autocomplete dropdown suggestions and input search box, when search box has rounded corners?

Tags: css, search, input, autocomplete

The title, body and images should be better explanatory now.

I have the following search box which I would like to keep the same, having rounded corners:

[image]

Now, when a user uses the search box once, the autocomplete suggests text like seen in the following pic:

[image]

What I have right now in CSS is this

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 19px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
}
```

And the html is pretty simple like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <fieldset>
  <input name="text" type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter text..." required="">
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

From user suggestions in the comments a good approach would be to set the border-radius to 0 on the bottom 2 corners however I don't know how to achieve this only for when the autocomplete appears, so not the first time user uses the input search box.

Can this be done in CSS or would one need Javascript ?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: It's not a select element, it is a search box and it might be my browser (mozilla) making the suggestions (previously used keywords) drop down, just like you have the suggestions on google search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `border-radius` property with multiple parameters working differently as

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 19px 19px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
}
```

For more details :https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Answer (score -1):

You can use the shorthand for border-radius to style the different corners independently: `border-radius: 19px 19px 0 0;`

This line translates to:

- border-top-left-radius: 19px;
- border-top-right-radius: 19px;
- border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
- border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;

```css
.dropdown input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 19px 19px 0 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown .input-dd {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input>
  <div class="input-dd">
  asd
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make this property active only when user clicks inside the search box and only when the drop down suggestions appears ?

Comment: This depends on what select thing you are using for this. But in very general terms, you would want to create a class with only setting the border-radius and applying this class to the input on a trigger from your select thing

Comment: Can you edit your question with your html also? So we can see what you have cooking? ‍

Comment: This is not what I want. Maybe I'm misleading with the lack of details in my question. I will update the question shortly